# Recursively generate non-overlapping schedule

Tags: ruby

I'm working through some careercup.com questions and I'm stumped on [this one](https://www.careercup.com/question?id=5682055978418176) in trying to recursively implement it in Ruby.  Basically, the goal is to generate non-overlapping schedules given a set of hour long movies and their showtimes.

```
def recursive_scheduler(movies, schedule = {})
  movie, showtimes = movies.first

  showtimes.each do |showtime|
    if !schedule.has_key?(showtime)
      schedule[showtime] = movie
      if movies.length > 1
        if recursive_scheduler((movies.reject { |m| m==movie }), schedule)
          return true
        end
      else
        puts "found schedule: #{schedule}"
        return true
      end
    end
  end
  return false
end

movies = { "The Shining" => [14, 15, 16],
           "Kill Bill"  => [14, 15],
           "Pulp Fiction" => [14, 15] }

recursive_scheduler(movies)
```

Comment: That's some code. What's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

This problem is an [assignment problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem), which is a special case of the [transportation problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transportation_theory_(mathematics)), which in turn is a special type of [linear programming problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming).

The variables are of the form x<sub>ij</sub>, which equals `1` if movie `i` is assigned to timeslot `j` and equal to `0` otherwise. There are two sets of constraints, one that ensures that each movie is assigned to exactly one timeslot and the other that permits at most one movie to be assigned to each timeslot. The objective function (to be maximized or minimized) is arbitrary (all variable coefficients are set equal to zero, for example) as we are seeking any *feasible* solution.

It follows that the problem could be solved with a general-purpose LP code (one that implements the *Simplex* algorithm, for example) or with a specialized algorithm for solving assignment or transportation problems. (See the links for details.) Regardless of the algorithm selected, it will produce a feasible schedule if one exists.

Comment: Liked this for academic explanation, informative without just handing over a functioning answer

Answer (score 0):

I won't solve it all, but give you some hints.

Given:

```
movies = { "Shining" => [14, 15, 16], 
     "kill bill" => [14, 15], 
     "Pulp fiction" => [14, 15] }
```

You can invert that hash into a hash of each time with an array of movies:

```
> times=movies.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k]=[] }) {|(k,v), h| 
                  v.map {|t| h[t] << k}
                  }.sort_by {|k, v| k}.to_h
=> {14=>["Shining", "kill bill", "Pulp fiction"], 15=>["Shining", "kill bill", "Pulp fiction"], 16=>["Shining"]}
```

Then you can take a [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of the values arrays and keep the uniques to deduce what the order has to be:

```
> schedules=times.values[0].product(*times.values[1..-1])
                  .select {|arr| arr.uniq.length == arr.length}
=> [["kill bill", "Pulp fiction", "Shining"], ["Pulp fiction", "kill bill", "Shining"]]
```

(Hint: Taking an Cartesian Product can be expressed recursively -- I just used Ruby's built in method as a shortcut)

So your result will be one of those two schedules.

Finally:

```
> times.keys.zip(schedules.transpose).map {|t,m| [t, m.uniq.join(' or ')]}.to_h
{14=>"kill bill or Pulp fiction", 15=>"Pulp fiction or kill bill", 16=>"Shining"}
```

Good luck!